# Написать программу на Си, которая находит в строке слова, имеющие одинаковые символы, и записывает их в другую строку без пробелов

Tags: c, массивы, строки

На вход поступает строка(с клавиатуры) слов(не обязательно существующих), разделенных одним пробелом. Требуется найти среди них слова, в которых есть одинаковые буквы, и вывести их на экран в виде строки без пробелов.

- **Например:**
- *input = "ggghghhghg qwerty ssoga zxcvb sssuper"*
- *output = "ggghghhghgssogasssuper"*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int m = 0, n = 0, d = 0;
    char words[1001];
    char curword[101];
    char finwords[1001];
    printf(">Enter the string of words (under 1000 symbols):\n");
    fgets(words, sizeof(words)-1, stdin);
    for (int i = 0; i<strlen(words)-1; i++) {
        if (words[i] != ' ') {
            curword[m] = words[i];
            m++;
        } else if (words[i] == ' ') {
            for (int j = 0; j<strlen(curword)-2; j++) {
                for (int k = j+1; k<strlen(curword)-1; k++) {
                    if (curword[j] == curword[k]) {
                        n = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (n == 1) {
                for (int j = 0; j<strlen(curword)-1; j++) {
                    finwords[d] = curword[j];
                    d++;
                }
                n = 0;
            }
            memset(curword, 0, sizeof(curword));
            m = 0;
        }
    }
    printf(">Result is\n");
    puts(finwords);
    return 0;
}
```

После запуска выдает невнятные символы, либо теряет последний символ в каждом выведенном слове.

Answer (score 0):

Разбираться в программе, которая:

1. Не разбита на функции, хотя это явно нужно сделать
2. Не содержит ни одного комментария
3. Зачем-то использует *memset()* хотя в этом явно нет никакой необходимости
4. ...

Нет ни малейшего желания. Рекомендую Вам переписать её с нуля, с двумя улучшениями:

1. Для разбивки строки на отдельные слова используйте стандартную фу-цию *strtoc()* (http://all-ht.ru/inf/prog/c/func/strtok.html)
2. Для поиска повторяющихся в слове букв напишите **отдельную** функцию.

Функция должна быть организована приблизительно так:

```
/*
  word - обрабатываемое слово
  return - 0- нет повторений, не 0 - есть повторенния
*/
int check(char *word) {

   int counts[52]; // a..z, A..Z
   int j;

   for (j=0; j<52; j++) counts[j] = 0;
   for (j=0; j<strlen(word)-1; j++) {
      counts[word[j] - 'a']++;
    }
    
   for (j=0; j<52; j++) if (counts[j] > 1) return 1;

   return 0;
}
```